# Random sample with probability to proportion to size

Tags: r, stat

I am in a statistical project, I have a table with words and the frequency that each one has in a text, what I want is a sample that has as a result the words that have the most frequency

Hello good afternoon, I hope someone can help me.

I have a table with words and how often each one appears in a text.

```r
word <- c("banana", "watermelon", "water", "apple", "blue", "sky")
freq <- c("10", "2", "5", "8", "2", "1")

table < -cbind.data.frame(word,freq)
#        word    freq
# 1     banana   10
# 2 watermelon    2
# 3      water    5
# 4      apple    8
# 5       blue    2
# 6        sky    1

sample(table$freq,2)
# [1] 2 5

word <- c("banana", "watermelon", "water", "apple", "blue", "sky")
freq<- c("10", "2", "5", "8", "2", "1")

table<-cbind.data.frame(word,freq)
sample(table$freq,2)
```

I want is:

```r
# [1] 10 8
```

Comment: Don't put numbers in quotes, that makes them strings not numbers.

Comment: You also don't have `pal` in your list of data sets, for your second `cbind` call.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I just put it that way for the example, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

If you want weighted probability of words based on your `freq` (converted to `integer`), then perhaps

```r
sample(tb$freq, size = 2, prob = tb$freq)
```

Let's see what the tendency is for this to prioritize the words we think we should be getting. For demonstration, I'll sample the `word` based on their `freq` (since that makes more sense to me), you can move variables around as you see fit.

```r
samps <- replicate(1000, sample(tb$word, size = 2, prob = tb$freq))
str(samps)
#  chr [1:2, 1:1000] "water" "apple" "water" "banana" "watermelon" "banana" ...
sort(table(samps))
# samps
#        sky watermelon       blue      water      apple     banana 
#         93        151        166        370        572        648
```

The `replicate` call gives us a `matrix`, so sorting the frequencies, we see that `banana` is more likely than all others.

We can see that the proportions are about right with

```r
sort(table(samps)) / sum(table(samps))
# samps
#        sky watermelon       blue      water      apple     banana 
#     0.0465     0.0755     0.0830     0.1850     0.2860     0.3240 
tb$pct <- tb$freq / sum(tb$freq)
tb <- tb[ order(tb$pct), ]
tb
#   freq       word        pct
# 6    1        sky 0.03571429
# 2    2 watermelon 0.07142857
# 5    2       blue 0.07142857
# 3    5      water 0.17857143
# 4    8      apple 0.28571429
# 1   10     banana 0.35714286
```

---

Data

```r
word <- c("banana", "watermelon", "water", "apple", "blue", "sky")
freq <- as.integer(c("10", "2", "5", "8", "2", "1"))
tb <- data.frame(freq, word)
```